# Сборка .apk на сервере при commit в git

Tags: git, непрерывная-интеграция

Имеется небольшое приложение на Unity.
Стоит задача: при push'е в github нужно, чтобы на сервере (VPS Ubuntu) собирался apk файл, исходя из последнего push'а. Как это можно реализовать максимально быстро? 
Заранее благодарен за ответы!

Comment: Да, да, continuous integration — действительно то, что вам надо. Только в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Вопрос в том, чем лучше воспользоваться новичку, для маленького проекта, в котором нет необходимости в сложной настройке.

Comment: Тем, что предлагают сервисы (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, ...).